# Creating an edge list from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

I'd like to create an edge list with weights as an attribute (counts number of pair occurrences - e.g., how many months have the pair a-b been together in the same group).

The dataframe contains a monthly snapshot of people in a particular team (there are no duplicates on the monthly groups)

| monthyear | name |
| --- | --- |
| jun2020 | a |
| jun2020 | b |
| jun2020 | c |
| jul2020 | a |
| jul2020 | b |
| jul2020 | d |

The output should look like the following (it's non-directional so a-b pair is the same as b-a):

| node1 | node2 | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 2 |
| b | c | 1 |
| a | c | 1 |
| a | d | 1 |
| b | d | 1 |

I managed to create a new dataframe with the names combinations using the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=list(combinations(df['name'].unique().tolist(), 2)), columns=['node1', 'node2'])
```

Now I'm not sure how to iterate over this new dataframe to populate the weights. How can this be done?

Comment: It's unclear to me. How weight is calculated? Can you show us?

Comment: Just a clarification on your output. Should there also be a node pair of A-C? Since there are A-D

Comment: Can there be duplicate values within the same month? For example 2 rows with `a` when `monthyear=jun2020`.

Comment: No duplicates on the month groupings

Comment: yes, there should be an extra a-c in the output, I'll add it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there are no duplicates within each `monthyear` group, you can get all 2-combinations of names within each group and then group by the node names to obtain the weight.

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_combinations(group):
    return pd.DataFrame([sorted(e) for e in list(combinations(group['name'].values, 2))], columns=['node1', 'node2'])

df = df.groupby('monthyear').apply(get_combinations)
```

This will give you an intermediate result:

```
            node1 node2
monthyear              
jul2020   0     a     b
          1     a     d
          2     b     d
jun2020   0     a     b
          1     a     c
          2     b     c
```

Now, calculate the weight:

```
df = df.groupby(['node1', 'node2']).size().to_frame('weight').reset_index()
```

Final result:

```
  node1 node2  weight
0     a     b       2
1     a     c       1
2     a     d       1
3     b     c       1
4     b     d       1
```